# Can't retrieve data from controller to view page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a simple project which is a BMI calculator. Every time I hit the 'calculate' button the page posts the data with the DIV element for a second then the page refreshes.

Here's my code from controller:

```
<?php

class Cal extends BaseController
{
    protected $helpers = ['url', 'form', 'text', 'html'];
    
    public function calc(){

        return view('calc');
    }

    public function calculator(){

        $bmi = new BMI();

        $height = $this->request->getPost('height');
        $weight = $this->request->getPost('weight');
        $bmicalc = $weight/($height*$height);
        $result;
        
       if($bmicalc <= 18.5){
        $result = "Underweight";

       }elseif($bmicalc > 18.5 AND $bmicalc<=24.9){
           $result = "Normal weight";
       }elseif($bmicalc > 24.9 AND $bmicalc<=29.9){
           $result = "Overweight";
       }elseif($bmicalc > 30.0){
           $result = "OBESE";
       }elseif($bmicalc > 31.0){
        $result = "OBESE 2";
       }

         $bmiInsert = array(
 
          
             'weight' => $this->request->getPost('weight'),
             'height' => $this->request->getPost('height'),
             'res' => $result,
 
 
         );

         $data = [
            'res' => $result,
        
        ];

            $bmi->insert($bmiInsert);
        
          return view('calc', $data);
     }

     
}
```

Here's my code for my view page:

```
<div class="try">
        <?php
                
                if(isset($res[0]))
                echo "Your BMI is  ", "$res";
      
                ?>
    
    </div>
```

Now here's the script that I've tried already:

```
$(".btn-check").click(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $(".try").css('display', 'block');  
           event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

I've also tried changing the button type into "button" instead of "submit" but still no avail.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass event as an function parameter to submit to prevent default behaviour

```
$(".btn-check").click(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            $(".try").css('display', 'block');  
           event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! with event.preventDefault(); it cannot refresh the page therefore it cannot retrieve the data. It feels like the page needs to reload before posting the data from my controller.  It only shows my div but not the data.

Comment: can you provide codepen link